# Cannot pass additional arguments to group_map

Tags: r, dplyr

I can't pass additional arguments to group_map. The following code returns the error

> "Error in (function (data, sumFirst)  : unused argument
>   (dots[[2]][[1]])"

```
library(dplyr)

data(mtcars)

myFunction2 <- function(data, sumFirst) {
  sumFirst
}

by_carb <- mtcars %>% group_by(carb)

group_map(by_carb, myFunction2, sumFirst=2)
```

I saw this thread on the topic, which makes me think I might be a know issue
https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4509

Is there any work around?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is your expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah, I'm trying to apply a function to all the groups in a grouped dataframe. The function above is a trivial, but it illustrates the problems. I don't see why I can't pass arguments to group_map by putting them in the dots argument. The documentation says that I should be able to do that the same way as we can for other functions like lapply, for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you need, but you can get group_map working like this:

```
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)
myFunction2 <- function(data, sumFirst) {
  sumFirst
}
mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% group_map(~myFunction2(.x,2))
```

Ok based my limited knowledge on the underworkings of group_map, in the vignette it says:

> If a *function*, it is used as is. It should have at least 2 formal
>   arguments.

If I read the [source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/group_map.R) correctly, so the first argument is the data, and the second is the keys, so a backbone to get it working is, using a different function (so we can see it really works):

```
group_map(by_carb,.f=function(data,keys)colMeans(data))
```

Now if you want to pass a custom function, then it will be:

```
group_map(by_carb,.f=function(data,keys,func)func(data),func=colMeans)
```

And you can check the results which i will not print here. It's the same as if we do, which is easier to write (i think):

```
group_map(by_carb,~colSums(.x))
```

Comment: thanks. `group_map(by_carb, ~myFunction2(.x,2))` gets it working, and I can generalise that to work for more useful functions with any number of arguments. I'm still not sure why the documentation ([link](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_map.html)) indicates that additional arguments can be passed in the dots, the same way as for example lapply works. when that doesn't seem to be the case.